# Python program to produce dictionary of file names, extensions, path, creation times, and sizes, and output them to a json file

Tags: python, dictionary, path, size, file-extension

```
import os, json, time

path = "C:\\Users\\Marius\\Desktop\\homework" #se defineste adresa

with os.scandir(path) as listOfEntries:
    for item in listOfEntries:
        
        data={}
        if item.is_file():
            filename_ext=os.path.splitext(item)
            size=(os.path.getsize(item))
            creation=(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(item)))
            extension=(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(item))[1])
            
            if filename_ext not in data:
                data[item.path] = {'name': item.name, 'path': path, 'extension': extension, 'creation': creation, 'size': size}
          
print(data)
        
j_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

with open('files.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to make a python file to generate the results needed, but I need them to be as an output JSON file.

I want the results to be as an output to files.JSON, something like the following result, but with all the files from that specific folder:

```
{
     "C:\\Users\\Marius\\Desktop\\homework\\test.py": {
          "name": "test.py",
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Marius\\Desktop\\homework",
          "extension": ".py",
          "creation": "Sat Dec 26 08:39:59 2020",
          "size": 733
     }
}
```

Comment: What does your current code produce, and what’s wrong with it? Please also explain what you want to produce *in text* _in your question_ i.e. not as a link.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) What have you done to debug this?

Comment: You're saving a list into your `data[item.path]` key, you should save dict instead. Change `data[item.path] = [item.name,extension,path,size]` to `data[item.path] = {'name': item.name, 'extension': extension, 'path': path, 'size': size}`.

Comment: thank you @validname for the suggestion
once ran, it produces the following results, but with some unwanted empty parenthesis like {} and also the output is not printed to the JSON file

{'C:\\Program Files\\Bitdefender\\Bitdefender Security\\crlset.txt': {'name': 'crlset.txt', to be continued.....}}
{}
{'C:\\Program Files\\Bitdefender\\Bitdefender Security\\cryptprotectal.dll': {'name': 'cryptprotectal.dll', to be continued.....}
{}
{}
{'C:\\Program Files\\Bitdefender\\Bitdefender Security\\d3dcompiler_47.dll': {'name': 'd3dcompiler_47.dll', to be continued.... }}

Comment: @tripleee the image is hosted automatically on another website called imgur. 
It is not hosted on the stackoverflow servers. Why is it even an image option on the process to add a question post?!

Comment: Some things have to be pictures, but pictures of text are useless if for example a reader wanted to copy/paste the text. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which also says “DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.”

Comment: edited with the info @validname gave me, removed that picture of text and added wanted result. The code provided is basically printed the last file from the specified folder path with the required arguments.

Comment: I'm not grumpy, I'm hoping to help you help us help you. The link I provided explains a number of issues with posting text as images; foremost probably that you are requiring visitors to click through to the image to see what you are asking, which many potential answerers will not be willing to do, especially when they can anticipate needing to retype whatever is in the image if they want to google it or try to run the code.

Comment: The code provided in the question post give me as output in files.JSON just the last file with the specified information about it.
I want to have all the files present in the specified folder to be listed in the JSON file. 
So far it is just the last file listed and I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Why are you using a context manager (a `with` statement) around `os.scandir()`? That's decidedly odd, and I would not be at all surprised if that doesn't do something else than you want and expect. Again, what have you done to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
import os, json, time

path = "C:\\Users\\Marius\\Desktop\\homework"

data={}
with os.scandir(path) as listOfEntries:
    for item in listOfEntries:
            filename_ext=os.path.splitext(item)
            size=(os.path.getsize(item))
            creation=(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(item)))
            extension=(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(item))[1])
            if item.is_file():
                if filename_ext not in data:
                    data[item.path] = {'name': item.name, 'path': path, 'extension': extension, 'creation': creation, 'size': size}
print(data)
        
j_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

with open('files.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```